# How to assign a JavaScript variable in one file to use it in another file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to setup my popup size in all 20 pages. So I assign 
them in the file `central_var.js`:

```
var popup_height = 600;
var popup_width = 850;
```

This file is included in all my pages and used to define the popup size:

```
function MyPopup(process, equipment_id) {
    var form_css = {
        top: ($(window).height() - popup_height) /2 + 'px',
        left: ($(window).width() - popup_width) /2 + 'px',
        padding: '5px',
        width: popup_width+'px', 
        height: popup_height+'px', cursor: 'default' }
    url = "manage_equipment_form.php";
    $.post(url,{process:process,equipment_id:equipment_id},function(data){
        $("#divHiddenForm").html(data);
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#divHiddenForm'), css: form_css });
        $('.close').click(function() { $.unblockUI(); });
    })  
}
```

But I get the following error message in the JavaScript console:

> popup_height, width  is not defined

What should I do? Or do I need to assign a PHP varitable instead and use the PHP variable to echo inside the JavaScript code?

Comment: A JavaScript global variable is declared outside the function or declared with window object. It can be accessed from any function

Comment: Provided `central_var.js` is loaded *before* the script code trying to use those variables, and provided those variables are declared at global scope, they'll work.